# Google Drive search HTTP/REST

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to implement searching inside Google Drive using **Drive API (V3)** and **HTTP/REST**. I've found several examples of searching using client library but didn't get any using **HTTP/REST**. I have tried `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q: name contains note` but it gives all the files and folders.

Comment: You wouldnt really need a library for Rest would you?

Comment: "*Can anyone give me an example?*" isn't really a good-fit question here. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP Doesn't really need a client library / have.  Your going to have to Get your access token I recommend using [CURL](https://youtu.be/hBC_tVJIx5w).

The full request you would need for files.list would be something like this.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%20%3D%20%27test%27 HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

As stated in [search for files and folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files), if you use `contains` for the name, you need to enclose the name of the file with single quotes `'`. Hence your q string should be `q: name contains 'note'` and the sample url should be something like this `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%20contains%20%27note%27&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

You can use an application like PostMan to make the calls.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation, I didn't mean library for HTTP I mean examples of searching using HTTP

Comment: Searching just uses the q parameter, you don't need a library just add it as a query parm.   I dont think you are going to find anyone having created examples with pure HTTP most people use a programing language.

Comment: I wanted to know how to use the q param correctly I'm putting `q: name contains note` into the url but it didn't work. I've updated my question can you please take a look again

Comment: did you try what I showed its name='test'  you could also consult the  [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-shareddrives)  Yes i know its v2 but they dont document it for v3 and for the most part its the same.   You can also test it in the [tryme](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list?apix=true)

Comment: It is as what @DalmTo suggested, use [api explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22name%20contains%20%27note%27%22%7D) to test/generate a sample http curl request. It is also stated in the [search for files and folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) that if you use `contains` for the name, you need to enclose the name of the file with single quotes `'`. Hence your url should be something like this `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name%20contains%20%27note%27&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`